# How to properly use twitter's widget.js from React?

Tags: javascript, twitter, reactjs

My react application intends to display tweets. I used the embedded tweet approch, my react application creates  `<blockquote>` and then I call `twttr.widgets.load()` in my `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const dom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  if (twttr) {
    twttr.widgets.load(dom);
  }
}
```

I now need to load globally `twttr` object for that I need to use this html tag:

```
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charSet="utf-8"></script>
```

I put it in my server code, in the `<head>` tag, it should be ok, as it is an async script tag.

I can't help but wonder if I'm doing it the right way ? Should I embed the `widgets.js` script in my application ? Or is there a more subtle way of inserting global objects from remote JS libraries ?